# What format is an uncompressed MP3 file in?

Tags: mp3, file-format, compression

I have seen that, leaving aside header and other structure data, a compressed file format still has some structure in its main data, and it can be compared to another, uncompressed format.

For instance, if the image date of a GIF file gets decompressed, it basically becomes the same as an indexed BMP file (using a palette and pixels that index a palette offset), and maybe with rows vertically inverted because of the BMP specification, but basically the very same data sequence.

**So, if an MP3 gets decompressed, what file format would it be represented in? A WAV file, or something else?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get are raw samples. You can write these easily (i.e. simply dump them) in a WAV file, although you still have to output the WAV header manually.